# How to Filter out data ranges when start and end dates are given?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have been given a set of start dates and stop dates for working days, I have also been given the working days and the daily rate. A person works a certain amount of days between for example Jan 1st 2018  and Feb 10th 2018, now the user wants to generate a report for cost from Jan 15 to Feb 15, how would I find out the number of working days for this person.

I've tried using the date filters on Excel but when I filter for February then January disappears. And it doesn't work since the guy worked 15 days in January and 10 days in February, so the month filter is useless. I'm stuck.

[image]

Comment: Please mock up some data and expected output.  Then [edit] the question to include this mock up.  The explanation is hard to understand without a visual representation.

Comment: Ive added an image

Comment: How are we supposed to now which days belong to which month?  Do we assume Monday - Friday only?

Comment: Yes working day are considered from mon - friday

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT to iterate the days in from the start to the finish and find if the dates fall in the Month provided and are Monday - Friday then multiply that by the daily rate:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT(ROW(INDEX($XFD:$XFD,A2):INDEX($XFD:$XFD,B2)),"mmmm") =E5)*(WEEKDAY(ROW(INDEX($XFD:$XFD,A2):INDEX($XFD:$XFD,B2)),2)<6)*D2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that your data is set up in a table. Then, from the Autofilter dropdown arrow in the column header, go to Date Filters, then use the Between filter.

More on Autofilter can be found at this Microsoft support link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-autofilter-to-filter-your-data-7d87d63e-ebd0-424b-8106-e2ab61133d92

Comment: Yes i have tried this, but the between filter does not work for working days from jan 15, it will fiter out the result as a whole